# How to protect entries in Google Calendar from being changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I currently export data from several Google Calendars to Google Sheets for my business. I now need to look into protecting that data. Is there a way I can stop the Google Calendar entries from being changed before a certain date?

Comment: Are you trying to protect your calendar or entries to a google sheet? Your title reads calendar, but then you mention you import to google sheets?

Comment: The original data is in google calendar, and my script brings all data within a certain date range automatically every 30mins., so I thought it would be easier to lock the data in google calendar.

Comment: In answer to your direct question, you can't modify security to an entire calendar based on a certain date...? Given that you're astute enough to write a script between the apps, you probably know that. Without more information or a more clear illustration of objective, this question probably won't get addressed.

Comment: Thanks, pgSystemTester - yep I thought that might be the case, I was hoping there was a way around it. Thank you for your help. Back to the drawing board for a bit while I think of way around this. I will reword my question and repost - thank you either way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to prevent that the calendar events in a Google Calendar be edited is by setting the calendar sharing options properly and by unchecking the Modify Event checkbox used to allow guests to edit the event. Just in case that you don't know it, a calendar can't be protected from its owner.

Related

- [An event that is guests can modify is not update via google calendar api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63259190/1595451)
- [Updating/Patching an event via the Google Calendar API as the Organizer of the event doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70251228/1595451)

Comment: Thanks Ruben - yeah I thought as much thankyou for the clarification - I will look at something else.